# VS 2012 SSIS Data Flow Designer Source Assistant Error: [SSIS.Pipeline]: Component ", clsid {4CAC ... Could not be created

Tags: oracle, ssis-2012, visual-studio-2012

I am creating my first SSIS package to support the E of our ETL from an external Oracle database to our internal SQL Server 2012 databse.

Using Visual Studio 2012 and I have installed the Microsoft Oracle Connection Manager by Attunity 2.0

I had this working, then renamed and deleted some files, and tried to build it again when I ran into this problem.

When running Source Assistant, I receive the Visual Studio Error:

> The component could not be added to the Data Flow task.  Could not initialize the component.  There is a potential problem in the ProvideComponentProperties method.

There is an "Additional Information" section that references:

> Error at TERM [SSIS.Pipeline]: Component ", clsid {4CAC6073-BCA7-430E-BD29-68A9F0012C6D}" could not be created and returned error code 0x80070005 "Access is denied.", Make sure that the component is registered correctly.
>
> Error at TERM [ [3]]: The component is missing, not registered, not upgradeable, or missing required interfaces.  The contact information for this copmonent is "".

Note: "TERM" is the name of the Data Flow task (named after the table I want to copy with SSIS.

This clearly looks like registry damage to me, so I had uninstalled the Attunity copmnent and re-installed it; and I ran a repair on Visual Studio 2012 (in that order); rebooted, etc.

No luck so far.

Anyone ever seen this before and/or have any ideas how to get back to a working SSIS development?

I am working on a development box, my Oracle Connection tests fine, and I can also connect fine to my SQL Server 2012 instance as well.

Comment: Considering doing a repair my SQL Server 2012 client stuff to see if that works.

Comment: Note also that I have not been able to figure out how to see the Oracle Source component in the toolbox.  Perhaps I should not be using the Source Assistant?

Comment: Ran a SQL Server 2012 Repair, which did not finish, because it was looking for SSDT 2012 install files (which SSDT 2012 removes after the install :( ).  Then I did a re-install of SSDT 2012 and rebooted - still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repairing and/or Re-installing Microsoft Connection Manager for Oracle by Attunity, VS 2012, and SSDT 2012 followed by a reboot enabled me to finally see the `Oracle Source` and `Oracle Destination` SSIS components in the `SSIS Toolbox` window under the `Common` category.

While using `Source Assistant` component still causes the same error, dragging over an `Oracle Source` component succeeds.  Configuring the component to set the Connection Manager, Data Access mode ("Table" in my case) and "Name of the Table" work great now.

Clicking on the `Preview` button proved it's working by showing me actual data from my Oracle Source database.